# Angular: "btn" class disappear after toggled the button

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have an issue with the class changing button. I use the [ngClass] directive to change the button style ( Bootstrap classes). But when I click the button, the "btn" class disappears from the code, so instead get 'btn-success btn', I get only 'btn-success'. The button also takes a part in showing and hiding a paragraph with random text.

This is TS code:

````
<button type="button"
  (click)="onClick($event)"
  [ngClass]="{'btn-success btn': showPass, 'btn-danger btn': !showPass }">{{status}}
</button>

<p [hidden]="showPass"  >Secret password</p>```
````

and this is HTML:

```
  onClick(event: Event) {

    this.showPass=!this.showPass;
    this.status = this.showPass ? "Show me!" : "Hide me!"
    console.log(this.showPass)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the btn class is always going to be there, you can just do this instead:

```
<button type="button"
  (click)="onClick($event)"
  class="btn"
  [ngClass]="{'btn-success': showPass, 'btn-danger': !showPass }">{{status}}
</button>
```

Comment: I don't know why I thought, that ngClass changes all class attributes. That works, thanks!